# Typing ALT + 251 and ALT + 0251 at the keyboard produce different character entries

Tags: windows, unicode, character, ascii, rdlc

In Windows:

- when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>, I get a `√` character
- when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> get `û` character!

A leading zero doesn't have value.

Actually, I want get check mark(`√`) from  `Chr(251)` function in `Client Report Definition` (RDLC) but it gets me `û`!

I think it interprets four numbers as hex not decimal.

Comment: That "check mark" is actually a square root symbol rendered in a terrible font. See [mins' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29728978/539810) for a good explanation with links. The short version of the story: in WIndows, Alt+xxx gets the character code from the OEM code page while Alt+xxxx gets the character code from the "ANSI" code page, which is very likely Windows code page 1252. If you search "oem vs ansi windows" on Google, you'll find a lot of resources explaining the difference between the two code pages and probably a short bit about why they existed in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, but this seems wildly off-topic to me for Stack Overflow

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As you understood, +0251 is [ASCII character](http://accentcodes.com/), it does not represent a number.

You must understand that when you write 0 to the left of numbers it does not have any value but here it is ASCII codes and not numbers.

Comment: Ok, Code is just code. but why Chr(251) gets me 0251

Comment: @Mohammadreza:- Because the binary format of Chr(251) is also 11111011 ;)

Comment: @Mohammadreza:- Check this table for reference: http://www.roubaixinteractive.com/PlayGround/Binary_Conversion/The_Characters.asp

Comment: tnx, but how get chr(251)?

Answer (score 6):

Using a leading zero forces the Windows to interpret the code in the Windows-1252 set. Without 0 the code is interpreted using the OEM set.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>:

- You'll get `√`, because you'll use [OEM 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), where 251 is for square root.
- I'll get `¹`, because I'll use [OEM 850](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850), where 251 is for superscript 1.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>:

- Both of us will get `û`, because we'll use [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), where 251 is for u-circumflex.

This is historical.

**From ASCII to Unicode**

At the beginning of DOS/Windows, characters were one byte wide and were from the American alphabet, the conversion was set using the [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoding.

Additional characters were needed as soon as the PC was used off the US (many languages use accents for instance). So different [codepages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) were designed and different encoding tables were used for conversion.

But a computer in the US wouldn't use the same codepage than one in Spain. This required the user and the programmer to assume the currently active codepage, and this has been a great period in the history of computing...

At the same period it was determined that using only one byte was not going to make it, more than 256 characters were required to be available at the *same* time. Different encoding systems were designed by a consortium, and collectively known as *Unicode*.

In [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) "characters" can be one to four bytes wide, and the number of bytes for one character may vary in the same string.

Other notions have been introduced, such as [codepoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) and [glyph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph) to deal with the complexity of written language.

While Unicode was being adopted as a standard, Windows retained the old one-byte codepages for efficiency, simplicity and retro-compatibility. Windows also added codepages to deal with glyphs found only in Unicode.

Windows has:

- A default [OEM codepage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351419/what-is-oem-encoding) which is usually [437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) in the US -- your case -- or [850](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) in Europe -- my case --, used with the command line ("DOS"),
- the [Windows-1252 codepage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (aka *Latin-1* and *ISO 8859-1*, but this is a misuse) to ease conversion to/from Unicode. Current tendency is to replace all such *extended* codepages by Unicode. Java designers make a drastic decision and use only Unicode to represent strings.

When entering a character with the <kbd>Alt</kbd> method, you need to tell Windows which codepage you want to use for its interpretation:

- No leading zero: You want the OEM codepage to be used.
- Leading zero: You want the Windows codepage to be used.

**Note on OEM codepages**

OEM codepages are so called because for the first PC/PC-Compatible computers the display of characters was [hard-wired](http://www.seasip.info/VintagePC/pgc.html), not software-done. The computer had a character generator with a fixed encoding and graphical definitions in a ROM. The BIOS would send a byte and a position (line, position in line) to the generator, and the generator would draw the corresponding glyph at this position. This was named "text-mode" at the time.

A computer sold in the US would have a different character ROM than one sold in Germany. This was really dependent on the manufacturer, and the BIOS was able to read the value of the installed codepage(s).

Later the generation of glyphs became software-based, to deal with unlimited fonts, style, and size. It was possible to define a set of glyphs and its corresponding encoding table at the OS level. This combination could be used on any computer, independently of the installed OEM generator.

Software-generated glyphs started with VGA display adapters, the [code required for the drawing of glyphs](http://www.phatcode.net/res/224/files/html/ch26/26-02.html) was part of the VGA driver.